# Eclipse wants non-existent methods to be implemented

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

I have an application that I've been trying to get working with Java 8's RMI. I'm using eclipse Neon.3 on Windows 10 and it is complaining that I am not implementing methods of an interface that don't exist.  In trying to narrow down a separate issue, I've commented out one of the abstract methods of the interface.

After commenting out the one abstract method, the interface is then exported to a jar file; the jar file is then added to the build path of the server application that will implement the interface.

The interface:

```
package accessService;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public interface ApplicationAccessService extends Remote{

//public void                   connectClient(Long[] clientId)      throws RemoteException;
public HashMap<String, Long>    getClientConnections()              throws RemoteException;
public HashMap<String, Integer> getServerConnections()              throws RemoteException;

}
```

The implementing class:

```
package iap.util;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import accessService.ApplicationAccessService;

public class RemoteIAP implements ApplicationAccessService{

private final static HashMap<String, Integer>   SERVERS     = new HashMap<>();
private final static HashMap<String, Long>      CLIENTS     = new HashMap<>();

public RemoteIAP(){ }

//methods used by RMI interface--------------------------------------   
@Override
public HashMap<String, Integer> getServerConnections() throws RemoteException {
    return SERVERS;
}

@Override
public HashMap<String, Long> getClientConnections() throws RemoteException {
    return CLIENTS;
}
//end RMI methods-------------------------------------------------------
}
```

The error:

```
The type RemoteIAP must implement the inherited abstract method ApplicationAccessService.connectClient(Long[])
```

It seems to me, that eclipse is somehow maintaining artifacts from before commenting out the method in question. Restarting eclipse and rebooting my pc has done nothing to change this behavior. I don't know if this is a problem with java, the manner I'm adding the interface to the build path using the context menu's in eclipse, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, ide can read the old compiled `.class` file and somehow it does not replace with the new one after the build operation.

Change the class name and build again.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible that taking out the line and then exporting may have failed. Understand that in the .jar, it is the code in the compiled .class file that matters, not in the .java file. So if you hadn't recompiled before exporting, you could have an old version in the .jar

Comment: unfortunately, I hadn't been exporting the source with the jar, so I couldn't see what was actually in there.  Next time I run into this situation, though, I will be sure to check this.  Just note, that the above idea regarding changing the class name did resolve this problem.